# Run insight in VPS

Tags: blockchain, server, bitpay

I want to know if someone tried https://insight.is and use it currently...

I was thinking... create a 5USD droplet and install bitcore.io + insight.is, but I don't know how it works, if that will need to download the full blockchain or will work as the SPV/Lightning wallets?

Because I'm making a little donation script (and a little POS based on that, and I don't want to depend from blockchain.info API)

Can someone give me a light in this? Will bitcore+insight works in a 5USD VPS from DigitalOcean? because I really don't want to download all the blockchain (because that will mean more money for maintain the server and my budget it's not high as excepted currently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a blockchain vps out of box ready
http://www.linkuphost.com/blockchain.html
It comes with preinstalled and fully synchronized blockchain core and wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcore is based on Bitcoin Core and must download the entire blockchain. Furthermore, it builds more indexes than Bitcoin Core does, so it will require more computing power and disk space than Bitcoin Core usually does. It probably won't be able to run on a cheap $5 UPS, or if it does, it will not perform very well.

You cannot run an instance of Insight without Bitcore or downloading the full blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bitcore README](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-node/blob/master/README.md) suggests 4 GB memory and 500 GB disk. That combination will run you about $90/month from Digital Ocean ($40 per month for their cheapest server with 4 GB of memory, plus another $50 for an additional 500GB of storage.)  There's no way you can do it for $5.